# Is normalizing $P(\Omega)=1$ in probability theory arbitrary?

Tags: probability-theory, bayesian

When I first learned probability theory I was told that under the Kolmogorov axioms, normalizing the probability of the whole sample space to $1$ was arbitrary, and any other positive real number would have worked. I later came across Cox's theorem and alternative Bayesian constructions of probability theory, where I seem to remember a proof that the probability of the sample space *must* sum to $1$, but now I can't find that proof. Is this true or is my memory failing me? If it is, could someone provide a reference?

Comment: Normalizing to one is only arbitrary inasmuch as putting probabilities on a scale from zero to one is arbitrary. We could switch to units of percent and put it on a scale of $0$ to $100$ instead. Or we could do something weird and put it on a scale from $0$ to $\pi$. This arbitrary upper limit is the total measure of the space.

Comment: It is not exactly the same: think about a space $\Omega$ whose measure is equal to 2. For example in this case the Jensen's inequality doesn't hold and has to be corrected with some factors. This occurs in most of the mathematical equalities. So, at the end, it is possible but you have to be really careful with the factors that summon in every property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is.

Probability measures are defined to be positive non-trivial measures with $P(\Omega)=1$.

If you would define them as measures with e.g. $P(\Omega)=2$ then there is only one obstacle: inconvenience.

For instance two events $A, B$ will be defined to be independent iff $$\frac12P(A\cap B)=\frac12P(A)\frac12P(B)$$ or equivalently: $$2P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$$

I do not believe in the existence of a proof that $P(\Omega)=1$ is somehow necessary.